# confusing query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hi I have 3 table `xyz abc and pqr`,structure of `xyz` and `abc` is same ,but the query inside exists clause is confusing me ,why someone put the table `pqr` when there is no need of that ,even no joining is been done here with that table .

```
Insert into xyz 
select * from abc where exist (select 1 from pqr where abc.pk_id =1234)
```

> abc.pk_id is primary key of table xyz

**Note**:I have not written this query this is existing in production ,please reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly less confusing version of the same query might be:

```
Insert into xyz 
select * from abc where abc.pk_id = 1234 and exists (select 1 from pqr)
```

In other words, insert records from abc for the specified pk_id, when pqr is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for `pqr` table in this context the following query should do the same:

```
Insert into xyz 
select * from abc where pk_id =1234
```